# Send json array payload to backend endpoint in wso2 ei not working

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I'm new to wso2 ei and I'm trying to do an orchestration which gives me an error at the backend telling me that my payload is malformed.
the payload required by the backend is of this form

```
[
    {
        "data1": "value1"
    },
    {
        "data2":"value2"
    }
]
```

I added the data via a Payload Factory mediator as the format requires, then a **header of type** **application/json** and a property **messageType** **also defined on application/json** but I have the impression that the esb does not send the data as is to the backend.
Do you have a solution or is the error at my level? I've been struggling with this for 2 days.

Here is the code of the mediation in question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/telereleve" name="TeleReleveAPI"
    xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource faultSequence="FaillureSeq" methods="POST"
        uri-template="/index">
        <inSequence>
            <log>
                <property name="InitApiLog"
                    value="Lancement de l'API avec les données suivantes en entrée: " />
                <property expression="json-eval($)" name="DataSend" />
            </log>
            <propertyGroup>
                <property expression="json-eval($.univers)" name="univers"
                    scope="default" type="STRING" />
                <property expression="json-eval($.zone)" name="zone"
                    scope="default" type="STRING" />
                <property expression="json-eval($.periode_debut)"
                    name="PeriodeDebut" scope="default" type="STRING" />
                <property expression="json-eval($.periode_fin)"
                    name="PeriodeFin" scope="default" type="STRING" />
                <property expression="json-eval($.compteurs)"
                    name="compteurs" scope="default" type="STRING" />
            </propertyGroup>
            <script
                description="Initialisation de la liste des numeros au format de l'API externe"
                language="js"><![CDATA[var DataToPost = []
mc.setProperty("DataToPost", DataToPost)]]></script>
            <foreach expression="json-eval($.compteurs)">
                <sequence>
                    <propertyGroup>
                        <property expression="json-eval($.numero)"
                            name="NumCompteur" scope="default" type="STRING" />
                        <property expression="json-eval($.profile)"
                            name="Profile" scope="default" type="STRING" />
                    </propertyGroup>
                    <script
                        description="Constitution de la liste des numeros compteurs au format de l'API externe"
                        language="js"><![CDATA[var DataToPost=mc.getProperty("DataToPost")

var dataJson = {}
dataJson.register = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
dataJson.from = ""+mc.getProperty("PeriodeDebut")
dataJson.to = ""+mc.getProperty("PeriodeFin")
dataJson.device = ""+mc.getProperty("NumCompteur")
dataJson.fromInclusive = true
dataJson.toInclusive = true
print("Donnees constituée "+ JSON.stringify(dataJson))
DataToPost.push(dataJson)
print("Contenu liste "+ JSON.stringify(DataToPost))

mc.setProperty("DataToPost", DataToPost)]]></script>
                </sequence>
            </foreach>
            <script language="js"><![CDATA[var DataToPost = mc.getProperty("DataToPost")
var DataToPostJson = JSON.stringify(DataToPost)
print(typeof DataToPostJson)
mc.setProperty("DataToPostJson", DataToPostJson)]]></script>
            <log>
                <property expression="$ctx:DataToPostJson"
                    name="DataToPostJson" />
            </log>
            <call>
                <endpoint key="GetTokenEP" />
            </call>
            <property action="remove" name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS"
                scope="axis2" />
            <log>
                <property expression="json-eval($)" name="DataApiToken" />
            </log>
            <propertyGroup description="Token Data">
                <property expression="json-eval($.access_token)"
                    name="Token" scope="default" type="STRING" />
                <property expression="json-eval($.token_type)"
                    name="TokenType" scope="default" type="STRING" />
            </propertyGroup>
            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>
                    $1
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$ctx:DataToPostJson" />
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <header
                expression="fn:concat(&quot;Bearer &quot;, $ctx:Token)"
                name="Authorization" scope="transport" />
            <header name="Content-Type" scope="transport"
                value="application/json" />
            <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING"
                value="application/json" />
            <call>
                <endpoint key="MeteredDataEP" />
            </call>
            <log>
                <property expression="json-eval($)" name="APIData" />
            </log>
            <respond />
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence />
    </resource>
</api>
```

and the mediation code of GetTokenEP is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="token" name="TokenAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource faultSequence="FaillureSeq" methods="POST" uri-template="/">
        <inSequence>
            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>{"grant_type":"client_credentials"}</format>
                <args/>
            </payloadFactory>
            <header expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode('username:password'))" name="Authorization" scope="transport"/>
            <header name="Content-Type" scope="transport" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
            <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
            <call>
                <endpoint key="AuthEP"/>
            </call>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following property before the Call Mediator.

```xml
<property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2" />
```

To remove the unwanted headers add the following before creating the payload.

```xml
<property action="remove" name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2"/>
```

```xml
<property action="remove" name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2"/>
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
    <format>[{"profile":"profile1","date":"2023-09-20"}]</format>
    <args/>
</payloadFactory>
<header expression="fn:concat(Bearer', &quot; &quot;, $ctx:Token)" name="Authorization" scope="transport"/>
<header name="Content-Type" scope="transport" value="application/json"/>
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
<log>
    <property expression="$trp:Content-Type" name="ContentTypeHeader"/>
    <property expression="json-eval($)" name="BodySend"/>
    <property expression="$trp:Authorization" name="HeaderSend"/>
</log>
<call>
    <endpoint key="BackendEP"/>
</call>
```

**Update**

In order to debug this issue, first start with a simple API. For now, generate a token hardcode it in the integration flow, also hardcode the JSON payload the backend expects in the PLFactory and check whether you can invoke the service.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/telereleve" name="TeleReleveAPI"
    xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource faultSequence="FaillureSeq" methods="POST"
        uri-template="/index">
        <inSequence>
            <log>
                <property name="InitApiLog" value="Lancement de l'API avec les données suivantes en entrée: " />
                <property expression="json-eval($)" name="DataSend" />
            </log>
            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>[
                    {
                        "data1": "value1"
                    },
                    {
                        "data2":"value2"
                    }
                ]</format>
                <args/>
            </payloadFactory>
            <property value="Bearer 1234567890" name="Authorization" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
            <call>
                <endpoint key="MeteredDataEP" />
            </call>        
            <respond />
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence />
    </resource>
</api>
```

If the above doesn't work enable wirelogs and compare the direct call against the postman call and see what's the difference. In most cases adding the following two properties should resolve the issue if the backend is not able to process the payload.

```xml
<property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2" />
<property action="remove" name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2"/>
```

Report back your findings.

Comment: I tried the solution, I still get the same error

Comment: @AristideEtoumi add your endpoint configuration as well. If you are using micro integrator enable Wire Logs as explained here and add the logs. https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/administer-and-observe/logs/configuring_log4j_properties/#wire-logs-and-header-logs If you are using Enteprise Integrator enable wirelogs as explained here. https://medium.com/@kasunaratthanage/enabling-wire-logs-log4j2-properties-in-wso2-enterprise-integrator-6-6-0-a5a251db139a

Comment: Thank you for displaying the logs, thanks to that I was able to see that the problem does not come from the ESB but rather from my mediation flow. In fact before calling this endpoint I call an endpoint which brings me an authentication token which I pass in the header to my final endpoint to receive the data. But it turns out that to receive the token I pass data in the form application/x-www-form-urlencoded and I realize that this content-type remains when sending the data to the 2nd endpoint and therefore the backend who expects to receive json sends me an error response.

Comment: I put a header and a property with the value "remove" but it still doesn't work, do you have a solution?

Comment: @AristideEtoumi Check the updated answer.

Comment: I switched to debugging mode and I noticed that the problem actually comes from the content type which does not change since the call to the first API which generates the token. However, a log tells me that the content type is "application/json" while debug mode shows me "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". I've tried everything to fix it but so far I don't have a solution.

Comment: @AristideEtoumi Did you try what I suggested? If so please add the complete integration and the wirelogs to your original question.

Comment: excuse my silence I was doing tests. I added the code you provided but it doesn't work either. After several internal tests I try to come up with a hypothesis. Could this problem be due to an invalid certificate? Because when I launch the backend API in postman I am told that the certificate is self-signed, so I followed the procedure to add it to the keystore in EI Studio. The backend is https, I did tests with a fake online api also having an https link and it works correctly without any problems. So I tell myself that my problem is due to the certificate. What do you think about it?

Comment: I want to add the complete integration code but the number of characters allowed for a comment is quickly reached, is there another way for me to send it to you?

Comment: @AristideEtoumi Edit your Original question and add it there. Also if it's a SSL issue you should see a relevant error in the logs.

Comment: I've updated my original question, you can see the entire mediation code

Comment: @AristideEtoumi Check the update in the answer.

Comment: Finally, installing version 8.2 of the Integrator Studio was able to resolve the problem.